# IIS, Nginx and HttpListener benchmarking -- confused

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, nginx, httplistener

I am running a benchmark on my development machine (i7 CPU, 4GB RAM, Windows 7 64-bit) to determine which web server has the best performance to deliver static content, taking IIS and Nginx under consideration, as well as a custom console application using a HttpListener (.NET 4.5). I am using Apache Benchmark to see the requests per second (-c 1000 -n 10000) handled by each server

I cannot believe the results, Nginx served 1000 requests/second, IIS served 700 requests/second and the custom console application using HttpListener served 4500 requests/second. Something must have gone wrong, can anyone shed some light on this scenario and explain why I get these odd results?

Comment: You do not give any information that can be used to get back feedback. What tools you use, how you make the measures, any screen shot, anything at all.

Comment: You could use "Fiddler" to trace the http-requests during your benchmark. Any eye-catchers there?

Comment: I used Apache Benchmark, as stated in the question. The HTTP headers do not show anything special whatsoever, they all allow to keep connections alive and allow chucked responses for direct file streaming. I don't know what else I could show that might give a more clear image ...

Comment: How large was the response, IIS does not (kernel) cache static files above a certain size. Running AB locally? What type I7 processor was this, we've seen IIS (and nginx) pushing a lot more than that, but size matters :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, make sure there is not network envienvironment difference between them.

It depends on your configuration. For Nginx, eg: worker_connections, open_file_cache, sendfile, keepalive ......  All those parameters could influent your "ab -c 1000 ..." test result.

What is more, Nginx is not designed for Windows OS, but C# & HttpListener sure are.